# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\IM\IMlogin.php on line 36

Tags: php

Please help, where have i gone wrong..
Every time i am getting this error message: **Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\IM\IMlogin.php on line 36**

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>IM</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><b>IM</b></h1>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN">
</form>
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $dbname = "infernomesenger";
    $con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$dbname);

    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];
        $cid = "karisgreat";
        $cpass = "karkpranam";

        if($id == $cid && $pass == $cpass)
        {
            $_SESSION('loggedin') = true;
            $_SESSION('username') = $name;
            echo "<script>document.location.href = 'chatroom.php'</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong id or password";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, `$_SESSION['loggedin']` is the proper syntax for an array (which is what `$_SESSION` is). You can't use parenthesis because PHP thinks you're calling a function

Comment: OOOPS...!!! thanx for the help..